# How can I get arraylist out of the for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have

```
List<ABC> abcList = new ArrayList<ABC>();
ABC abc = new ABC();

for (int i = 0; i < abcList.length; i++) {
    abc.setX(5) 
    abc.setY(5-10) // just an example to easy to understand
    abcList.add(abc)
}
System.out.println(Integer.toString(offsetList.get(0).getY()));
```

I want the result is -5, but the log prints 0 and it's the same for the remains objects. I am learning java, so please tell me how can I get the arraylist out of the for loop?

Comment: how is offsetList related to abcList? is it just a typo?

Comment: yes,it is.I editted it,sorry :D

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to achieve, it is very confusing, for me at least.

Comment: format your code properly, the way I see it abc.setY hasn't been set at all

Comment: You need to move `ABC abc = new ABC();` into the `for` loop.

Comment: Also you are adding the same object ABC object several times, it is the same instance you keep changing X and Y, don't know what you wanna achieve but the `new ABC()` should be in the loop. How it supposed to cycle to `abcList.length` if you just created an empty list?

Comment: How your program compiles with `abcList.length`; You need to use `abcList.size();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-initialise your abc varible each time.

Also your arrayList is empty in the beginning. it will never get into the for-loop.

```
List<ABC> abcList = new ArrayList<ABC>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ABC abc = new ABC();//You have to re-initialise your variable each time.
    abc.setX(i);
    abc.setY(i - i * 2); 
    abcList.add(abc);
}
System.out.println(abcList.get(0).getY());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `for loop` and you have expected answer there.

For adding a single element to a `list`, you don't need a `for loop`.